# jQuery recursive wildcard selector from array and array push dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, recursion

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CastleBrav0/F22vS/)

I have many elements containing text in which I am using `parseInt()` to grab the values from a specific number of elements (based on the current month) and a specific selector wildcard and push those values into one of six arrays for use elsewhere.  I am trying to clean up the code and make a compact loop to complete all of this.

I am able to get everything to work if I use six separate `for` loops, but I thought I might try to see if it is able to be done in one single loop.

So in the `for` loop below, I am trying to make the jQuery wildcard selector for the element ID be the current value of `i` (from `statusArray`) by trying something like `$('[id*=statusArray[i]])` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Then I would like to push the data into the predefined appropriate array by something like `statusArray[i]Array.push(...)` but that doesn't work either.  I've tried concatenating various ways but can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="jan_connected"></div>  <!-- left empty to test for NaN -->
<div id="jan_busy">100</div>
<div id="jan_noanswer">100</div>
<div id="jan_abandoned">100</div>
<div id="feb_minutes">100</div>
<div id="feb_totals_calls_c">100</div>
<div id="feb_connected">100</div>
<div id="feb_busy">100</div>
<div id="feb_noanswer">100</div>
<div id="feb_abandoned">100</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
var connectedArray = [];
var busyArray = [];
var noanswerArray = [];
var abandonedArray = [];
var minutesArray = [];
var callsArray = [];
//    var date = new Date();
//    var dateNumber = 1 + date.getMonth();
var dateNumber = 2;
var statusArray = ['minutes', 'total_calls', 'connected', 'busy', 'noanswer', 'abandoned']

for (i=0; i<dateNumber; i++) {
    // Below I would like the id* to equal the current value of the statusArray iteration
    if (isNaN(parseInt($('[id*=statusArray[i]]').slice(i).html()))) {
        statusArray[i]Array.push("0");   // Trying to push into the appropriate array dynamically
    } else {
        statusArray[i]Array.push(parseInt($('[id*=statusArray[i]]').slice(i).html()));
    }
}
```

Comment: `statusArray[i]Array.push`? What makes you think that's an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **syntax errors** in couple of places..

this line

```
$('[id*=statusArray[i]]')
```

supposed to be

```
$('[id*=' + statusArray[i] + ']')
```

And

```
 statusArray[i] Array.push("0");
```

should be

```
 statusArray[i].push("0");
```

**Push** method is available on a Array , but `statusArray[i]` is not an array but a string.

Looks like you are looking for something like this

```
var connectedArray = [];
busyArray = [];
noanswerArray = [];
abandonedArray = [];
minutesArray = [];
callsArray = [];
dateNumber = 2;
statusArray = ['minutes', 'total_calls', 'connected', 'busy', 'noanswer', 'abandoned'];
var obj = {
    'minutes': minutesArray,
        'totals_calls': callsArray,
        'connected': connectedArray,
        'busy': busyArray,
        'noanswer': noanswerArray,
        'abandoned': abandonedArray
};

for (i = 0; i < statusArray.length; i++) {
    $('[id*="' + statusArray[i] + '"]').each(function () {
        var val = $(this).html();
        if (isNaN(parseInt(val))) {
            obj[statusArray[i]].push("0");
        } else {
            obj[statusArray[i]].push(val);
        }
    });
}

    console.log('Minutes Array: ' + obj['minutes']);
    console.log('Total Calls Array: ' + obj['totals_calls']);
    console.log('Connected Array: ' + obj['connected']);
    console.log('No Answer Array: ' + obj['noanswer']);
    console.log('Abandoned Array: ' + obj['abandoned']);
    console.log('Busy Array: ' + obj['busy']);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F22vS/1/)**

Comment: Yes, changing the line to `$('[id*=' + statusArray[i] + ']')` fixes the one error I was having trouble with. Thank you!  As for the second, if I am unable to use **.push**, is there no way to write this loop to push the values into the appropriate array?  I might just need to use 6 for loops then..?

Comment: This works and is almost exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you so much!  I will need to do some tweaking on it to match my requirements but you helped me learn something new today!